# Show that f is continuous at 0, but discontinuous at c for all c/=0.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I showed that f is continuous at 0 by simply using the definition of continuity. However I have no idea how to prove the second party that f is discontinuous at c for all c/=0.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you define what it means for $f$ to be continuous? (I'll bet that your definition has something to do with sequences, and I'll bet even more that you'll have to use the hint.)

Comment: @T.Bongers I'm using the definition with epsilon and delta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show that your function is discontinuous at every irrational number $x$. Perhaps you can modify this to complete the question. One definition of continuity is that of *sequential continuity,* which says that $f$ is continuous at $z$ if, for all sequences $\{a_n\}$ which converge to $z$, we have 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(z).
$$

Now given our irrational $x$, we can find a sequence of *rational* numbers $\{q_n\}$ which converge to $x$. This is given in the hint; to see more about this, google something like "rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$." But now we have 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(q_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n=x
$$
by definition of $f$ and by our assumptions on $\{q_n\}$. Since $x$ is irrational, we know $x\neq 0$, so we have 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(q_n)=x\neq 0=f(x).
$$
Thus $f$ is not sequentially continuous at $x$, so $f$ is not continuous at $x$. Think you can go from here?

Comment: Let c /= 0. Take a sequence {xn} of rationals converging to c. Then f(xn) = xn → c. Also take a sequence {yn} of irrationals converging to c. Then f(yn) = 0 → 0. Since c /= 0, it follows that the limit of f at c does not exist. Hence f is not continuous at c. Is this right?

Comment: @Milos looks good

Comment: In your definition of sequential continuity I think it's $ lim f(a_n)=f(z)$

Comment: @JellyBelly you are correct. Will fix.